# Convert half to float in OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, opencl, precision

I apologize if this is trivial, but I've been unable to find an answer by google.

As per the OpenCL standard (since 1.0), the half type is supported for storage reasons.

It seems to me however, that without the cl_khr_fp16 extension, it's impossible to use this for anything?

What I would like to do is to save my values as half, but perform all calculations in float.

I tried using convert_half(), but that's not supported without the cl_khr_fp16.
I tried just writing (float) before the half for auto c-style conversion, didn't work eighter.

So my question is, how do I utilize half for storage?

I need to be able to both read and write half's.

Comment: does your device support the half type? it is optional, not required.

Comment: I apologize if that wasn't clear from my question.

No, my device does not seem to support the cl_khr_fp16 extension, which I know is optional.

None the less, the specification still says that I should be able to use half for storage purposeses.

You can see this here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/

double and the vector versions of double and half are optional, but half is part of the core OpenCL specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vload_halfN` and `store_halfN`. The halfN values stored will be converted to/from floatN.

Comment: You're correct. I missed those calls when reading the documentation. I was sure they required the cl_khr_fp16 extention and would read halfs and keep them in half format instead of converting to float.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since it wasn't mentioned in any of the other answers I thought I'd add: You can also use half float in OpenCL images and the `read_imagef` and `write_imagef` functions will do the conversion to/from float for you (cl_khr_fp16 extension not required). That extension is only for having variables in (and doing math in) half.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the type half is only supported on the GPU, but you can convert it to and back from a float fairly simply, as long as you know a bit about bitwise manipulation.

Have a look at the following link for a good explanation on how to do so.

```
ftp://ftp.fox-toolkit.org/pub/fasthalffloatconversion.pdf
```

Comment: Link doesn't work (tried getting it from google also, so must be the site that's offline)

I think I found the document however.

I'll look into it and flag this as the answer if it works :)

Thanks!

Comment: Thats weird the link works fine for me both at home and at work